# Sprockets throws NoMethodError while pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sprockets

I am upgrading my app to ruby 2.6.5 and it seems sprockets 4.0.2 is the cause of the issue.  Most answers I've found involve downgrading to sprockets 3.7.2 (which I'm using locally), but when the assets get compiled during the Heroku push, I get the following error:

```
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for #<Regexp:0x00005582ab94a790>
remote:        /tmp/build_f56a8b75/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/uri_utils.rb:78:in `valid_asset_uri?'
remote:        /tmp/build_f56a8b75/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:27:in `resolve'
remote:        /tmp/build_f56a8b75/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:79:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f56a8b75/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_f56a8b75/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
```

I've modified `config/initializers/assets.rb` to:

```
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << ["*.svg", "*.eot", "*.woff", "*.ttf"]
```

But the error is still occurring.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting this error as well. Have you figured out the issue yet? I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: I went with downgrading sprockets because I couldn't find a fix and needed to move along

Answer (score 0):

I also faces the same error.

I added below version specified gem due to downgrade sprockets and it deploys successfully.

Gemfile

```
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.0'
```